# Function to retrieve the application currently in use

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a function to determine which application (or the desktop if no windows are displayed on screen) is under user focus. However, it doesn't work for some applications such as the task manager… Indeed, the `OpenProcess` function (see code below) returns an invalid handle.

For now, I consider that the desktop has still the focus when it occurs but I would like to be able to retrieve the name of the Task Manager as I'm sure other applications behave the same way.

Any ideas how could I do it ? Also, if you know a more decent way (as I'm sure there is) to determine whether the user is on the desktop than checking if the windows title is empty, I'm eager to hear it.

Thanks.

```
std::wstring GetForegroundAppName() {
    HWND            hwnd = GetForegroundWindow(); //HWND is a handle to a Window while HANDLE is a handle to an object
    HANDLE          hprocess;
    //HWND hwndbis = GetDesktopWindow();
    int             titleSize = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
    const size_t    size = 500;
    std::wstring    appPath(size, '\0');
    std::wstring    appName;
    DWORD           processID;
    int             nbCharRetrieved;

    //
    //Find the path of the application being used
    //
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processID);
    hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION  | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, processID); 
    nbCharRetrieved = GetModuleFileNameEx(hprocess, NULL, &appPath[0], size);

    //
    //Do some checkings
    //
    if (nbCharRetrieved == 0) {
        //throw ?
        appPath.erase();
    }
    else if (nbCharRetrieved == size) {
        //throw ?
    }

    //
    //Fill in the name of the application being used or desktop.
    //

    int PosLastOccurence = appPath.rfind(L"\\", appPath.size());
    appName = appPath.substr(PosLastOccurence + 1, appPath.size()); //We don't care about the '\0' char

    if ((appName.empty() == true) || (titleSize == 0)) { //The user is currently on the desktop or the application being used couldn't be retrieved
    appName = L"Desktop";
    }
    return appName;
}
```

Comment: use `GetModuleFileNameEx` for get full path of exe the worst choice from all existing

Comment: You should call `GetLastError` and inspect the value returned.

Comment: You aren't checking **any** return values. Why?

Comment: PROCESS_VM_READ is a big demand, intuitively obvious from the ability to poke around in the process and discover secrets.  It cannot work when your program does not have sufficient rights on the kind of processes that protect themselves.  Like Task Manager, it runs with UAC elevation.  You'd need to likewise elevate your own process.

Comment: @RbMm : Could you explain me why ?

Comment: @Hans Passant : exact, the error returned after the call to OpenProcess is "5" (access denied).  Any ideas how I could accomplish the same functionnality otherwise then ?

Comment: Have you tried running your application with admin privilege?

Comment: because `GetModuleFileNameEx` read process memory and walk on LDR structs for get module path. also here exist 32-64 bit issue. this is the worst way. if you need path of exe you need use or `GetProcessImageFileName` or `QueryFullProcessImageName`. in both case you need only open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` (if you have debug priviledge you can open any process with this access). also begin from vista you can use `SystemProcessIdInformation` with `ZwQuerySystemInformation` - in this case you not need any privileges(and open process) at all.

Comment: you also can enumerate all processes in system and found related to your id. in this case you get the name only (without path) and here you again not need any privileges

Comment: At least next time bother to read the descriptions of the tags you use to see what they're meant for. The description for the "api" tag explicitly says in capital letters to never use it.

Comment: @tambre: The [tag:api] tag was suggested by the site, while entering the question. The fact that it pops open an info popup is not exactly easily discoverable. You shouldn't blame a new user who didn't second-guess the system. If you feel like the [tag:api] tag should not be used, request to have it removed over at Meta.

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager and other processes are running wither higher permissions than a standard process.  If you want PROCESS_VM_READ permissions you must also run your program as administrator.  This is the cause of your failure on only these processes.